# PHP & MySQL - Loop through results and display name and count for each entry

Tags: php, mysql, list, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to loop through a list of results from MySQL and display all the unique game names and the count for each in an HTML table format. It works fine up until the last row which doesn't display the name or count. If the last name has multiple rows then it displays the name but not the count.

My code:

```
$propertyGameQuery = "SELECT G.GAME_NAME FROM GAMES AS G, PROPERTY_GAMES AS PG WHERE PG.PROPERTY_ID=$cid AND G.ID=PG.GAME_ID ORDER BY G.GAME_NAME";
$propertyGameResult = mysql_query($propertyGameQuery);

$gameCount = 0;
$rowCounter = 0;
$number = mysql_num_rows($propertyGameResult);
$rws = mysql_fetch_assoc($propertyGameResult);
$starterName = $rws['GAME_NAME'];

while($propertyGames = mysql_fetch_assoc($propertyGameResult)) {
    $currentGameName = $propertyGames['GAME_NAME'];
    if(($gameCount == 0) or ($rowCounter == $number)){
    ?>
        <tr class="game-table"><td width="80%" title="<? echo $currentGameName; ?>" align="left" style="padding-left:5px;"><? echo $rowCounter ?> <? echo $currentGameName; ?></td>            
    <? 
    }
    if(($currentGameName == $starterName) or ($lastGameName == $currentGameName)){ 
        $gameCount = $gameCount + 1;    
    }else{
    ?>
        <td width="20%" align="center"><? echo $gameCount + 1; ?></td></tr>                             
    <? 
        $gameCount = 0;  
    } ?>
    <?
    $lastGameName = $currentGameName;
    $rowCounter++;
}
```

Comment: what do u want to show in the table ? just the game names ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to see a count for each game name, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all with the query

```
SELECT G.GAME_NAME, COUNT(*) as nb_games 
FROM GAMES G, PROPERTY_GAMES PG 
WHERE PG.PROPERTY_ID = $cid 
AND G.ID=PG.GAME_ID 
GROUP BY G.GAME_NAME
ORDER BY G.GAME_NAME
```

So then:

```
$sql = "SELECT G.GAME_NAME, COUNT(*) as nb_games"
    . " FROM GAMES G, PROPERTY_GAMES PG" 
    . " WHERE PG.PROPERTY_ID = $cid" 
    . " AND G.ID=PG.GAME_ID" 
    . " GROUP BY G.GAME_NAME"
    . " ORDER BY G.GAME_NAME";

$propertyGameResult = mysql_query($propertyGameQuery);
$counter = 0;
while(false !== ($rws = mysql_fetch_assoc($propertyGameResult)): $counter++; ?>
<tr class="game-table">
  <td width="80%" title="<?php echo $rws['GAME_NAME']; ?>" align="left" style="padding-left:5px;">  
    <?php echo $counter ?> <?php echo $rws['GAME_NAME']; ?>
  </td>
  <td width="20%" align="center">
    <?php echo $rws['nb_games']; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last row to show, you need to change:

```
if(($gameCount == 0) or ($rowCounter == $number)){
```

TO

```
if(($gameCount == 0) or ($rowCounter-1 == $number)){
```

This is because you are starting the count at 0 and don't put the row count until after this call.

You also should change:

```
if(($currentGameName == $starterName) or ($lastGameName == $currentGameName)){
```

TO

```
if((($currentGameName == $starterName) or ($lastGameName == $currentGameName)) && ($rowCounter-1 != $number)){
```

That is how to fix your code, but you could do this by optimizing your query.

Answer (score 0):

You call this function once outside the while loop it should, it should only be called inside the while loop to ensure all rows are outputted.

```
mysql_fetch_assoc( $propertyGameResult);
```